# Can't get past Facebook checkpoint after entering real name

Tags: facebook

Facebook wanted me to enter my real name, but when I did it didn't accept it. Now I get a blank page (checkpoint) after signing in and can't get to my page.

I could and did change my password, but that doesn't help. I didn't receive an email or text message. Other people can access my page and it doesn't say I'm blocked.

I have cleared my browser cookies and tried again in both Firefox and Internet Explorer, but still get redirected to the blank page (facebook.com/checkpoint).

Can anyone tell me how to get past the blank page?